# vscode remote-shh: switching user in the file explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-access, remote-server

I have VSCode with the extension `remote-ssh` installed. I connect to a remote host by `username` and `IdentityFile`.

To access certain files on the remote host, I have to switch users using `su <user>`. But when I switch users, I can only access the file in the terminal and not in the file explorer and therefore I'm unable to use the graphical editor of VSCode to edit my files.

Comment: Seems like an open issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/690

Answer (score 4):

You can modify your config file like this:

```
Host remote
....
RemoteCommand su otherUser
```

according to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/690#issuecomment-993857961

but remember to manually add

```
"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true,
"remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": true,
```

to your VSCode settings.json file,

and remember to test the command `su otherUser` in ssh terminal and make sure it doesn't ask for a password (which will not work with `RemoteCommand`)

For me, I use `RemoteCommand sudo su otherUser` and disable sudo password for my ssh user.

Took me a while to search answers and configure, now it works perfectly.

If you have any other questions, go to the issue and read the thread.

Comment: How to handle the case that it requires a password for 'sudo su - otherUser'

Comment: @kxiaocai As I mentioned in my answer, I disabled sudo password. Here is how to do that, but do it at your own risk. https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password

Answer (score 0):

add options in .ssh file:

```
Host remote
....
RemoteCommand su Username
```

and change vscode setting

```
"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true,
"remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": true,
```

delete remote you are trying to connect to in Remote.SSH: Remote Platform;